# $y''=y$, $x''=-x$. Write this equation in terms of the first-order system

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble with my homework on higher-order equations and their equivalent systems. :(

This is the problem:

Write this equation in terms of the first-order system.

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l} \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-x \\ \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=y \end{array} \right.$$

(Hint: Write each second-order equation as two first-order equations.

Answer (score 5):

If $X= \left( \begin{array}{c} x' \\ x \end{array} \right)$, then $X'= \left( \begin{array}{c} x'' \\ x' \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{c} -x \\ x' \end{array} \right)= \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} x' \\ x \end{array} \right)=AX$. You can do the same thing for $y$.